# Cannot find the certificate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, certificate, sql-server-2008-r2

We get a T-SQL (SQL Server 2008 R2) error on BACKUP CERTIFICATE:
ERROR_NUMBER 15151, SEVERITY 16, STATE 1, PROCEDURE -, LINE 8, MESSAGE: Cannot find the certificate 'certificate1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

We can see the certificate in master.sys.certificates.

Our pseudo-code:

- copy an unattached template_db to db1
- attach db1
- create certificate1 (in stored procedure in master db)
- generate @password
- CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY … ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE '+@certificate_name +…  (in stored procedure in db1)
- turn on Transparent Database Encryption for db1 using certificate1.
  (N'ALTER DATABASE '+@db_name+N' SET ENCRYPTION ON')
- N’BACKUP CERTIFICATE '+@certificate_name+N'
  TO FILE = '''+@certificate_file_path+N'''
  WITH PRIVATE KEY (
  FILE = '''+@private_key_file_path+N''',
  ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '''+@password+N''''

To try to work-around the error, we tested three ways with the BACKUP CERTIFICATE code in a different databases each time, including db1 and master.  All get the same error.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I can't vote up your answer because I don't have enough rep. Thank you for posting it! This was my problem, I needed to highlight the master database in order to backup a certificate that was stored in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We tried again, running BACKUP CERTIFICATE in the master DB, and it worked this time.